# Using aws-azure-login container on Windows Insider releases

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been setting up my laptop to use WSL2 as a model for other people in my company. I have made a lot of progress in creating a nice dev environment.

- I connected to the Windows Insider program: `Version 2004 (OS Build 19035.1)`
- I installed an Ubuntu 18.04 WSL and upgraded it to WSL 2
- I installed the edge version of Docker `2.1.6.1`

All of that works fine. Now I want to connect to my company AWS account which authenticates with Microsoft AD. So I downloaded the aws-azure-login container and ran

`docker run --rm -it -v \~/.aws:/root/.aws sportradar/aws-azure-login --configure`

... which ran perfectly fine.

But when I actually run

`docker run --rm -it -v \~/.aws:/root/.aws sportradar/aws-azure-login --configure`

... I get this error:

```
❯ docker run --rm -it -v \~/.aws:/root/.aws sportradar/aws-azure-login Logging in with profile 'default'... 
Using AWS SAML endpoint u/ ? Username: mark.chassy@virtualclarity.com ? 
Password: \[hidden\] 
We've sent a notification to your mobile device. 
Please open the Microsoft Authenticator app to respond. Unable to recognize page state! 
A screenshot has been dumped to aws-azure-login-unrecognized-state.png. 
If this problem persists, try running with --mode=gui or --mode=debug
```

When I try running in gui mode:

```
❯ docker run --rm -it -v \~/.aws:/root/.aws sportradar/aws-azure-login --mode=gui 
Logging in with profile 'default'...
Using AWS SAML endpoint u/ Error: Failed to launch chrome!  (chrome:15): 
Gtk-WARNING \*\*: cannot open display:   
TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/u/in/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:348:14)     
at ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener (/aws-azure-login/node\_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:338:60)     
at emitTwo (events.js:131:20)     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)     
at Process.ChildProcess.\_handle.onexit (internal/child\_process.js:198:12)
```

When I try running in debug mode:

```
❯ docker run --rm -it -v \~/.aws:/root/.aws sportradar/aws-azure-login --mode=debug 
Logging in with profile 'default'... 
Using AWS SAML endpoint 
Error: Failed to launch chrome!  (chrome:15): Gtk-WARNING \*\*: cannot open display:   
TROUBLESHOOTING: u/)     
at ChildProcess.helper.addEventListener (/aws-azure-login/node\_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:338:60)     
at emitTwo (events.js:131:20)     
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)     
at Process.ChildProcess.\_handle.onexit (internal/child\_process.js:198:12)
```

I get the same results when running in powershell or cmd. On the other if I run it on a mac, it works perfectly, so I don't think there is anything wrong with the container itself.

Has anyone gotten this to work on WSL 1, WSL 2, or even just on Windows 10 itself?

Answer (score 5):

you can try this command

`aws-azure-login --mode=gui --mode=debug --no-sandbox  --enable-chrome-network-service  --no-verify-ssl`

Comment: sorry, I have moved over to a linux laptop now, so I can't verify.

Answer (score 0):

On WSL 2 version, "cannot open display ..." can be solved using:

```
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0
```